# What tools to deploy webserver running numpy behind?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, webserver

If I am given a dataset (say excel file), I would like to deploy a webserver on which I upload this excel file, it runs python/numpy code and displays some figure.
I could also have some checkboxes on the website that would change the parameters in the code.

What tools would you recommend for doing that? What would be the easiest way?

For now I have the python code on jupyter notebook and use:

`from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html`

`embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[fig])`

to see my figure (fig) locally, by running: `python -m http.server 8080`

I would like this to be deployed and choosing the file to upload.

Comment: i suggest you do a little google research and then come back with a more specific question. Try "deploy jupyter notebook on server".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Django may be the best option for you. It requires Python knowledge and basic HTML/CSS -for basic usage-, that is why I thought it is the best option.

You can develope python scripts and user can able to modify the input for that python script and easily create an dashboard with graphics/calculations.

You may want to check Vitor's website:
[Simple is the Best by Vitor Freitas](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Github repo to host your code, and then share it via [MyBinder.org](https://mybinder.org/).  An example, that is simpler than yours, but like what you describe in some ways is [here](https://github.com/fomightez/bendit-binder). When you get there click the `launch` badge and a temporary session will spin up. In the notebook that comes up, you can do `Run All Cells` under the `Run` menu. The session dies after 10 minutes of inactivity. You can download useful information. See more about the MyBinder project [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#preparing-a-repository-for-binder). I am taking advantage of the drag and drop for file upload that comes with JupyterLab here but there are file upload widgets (see below).

That example one doesn't have fancy widgets like toggles to make the choices but you can add them. For example, see the [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) demo. (Click `launch binder` button on the page.) You'll see you can have the widgets in the notebook or in the 'appmode'. You can make the interactions with the [widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) fancier, too. Some examples featured in [the Voila gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/) will give you more of an idea of what is possible with the widgets and communicating to your underlying python. All those are on Github and served via temporary sessions from MyBinder.org. Keep in mind those apps can run in the notebook if you want that. The widgets work there in the notebook versions as well, too. And you can directly link to the notebook mode if you prefer, as shown under the heading 'Direct links to start out in notebook mode' [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila).